# Debian post installation triggers often make my system unusable! Is there something I can do?

Tags: dpkg, mono

Mainly it's the menu and monodoc-base triggers that cause the problem. Recently monodoc base has become a major pain. It keeps saying there are a bunch of errors, and uses up 100+ CPU% and makes it impossible to do a thing. I've had to force it to stop so many times now.

<s>I don't want to lose monodevelop, but will a reinstall work to stop the hell?</s> I got kinda mad and went ahead and did it. Gonna see how it goes, but so far, it's improved.

Comment: Could you give an example of the errors from monodoc-base?

Comment: I just removed it lol. I'll have to wait till it reinstalls to launch epiphany and get the link to the error back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it O.o.
Removing monodoc-everything, and reinstalling that + monodevelop worked. Even the post-install trigger menu is behaving. Looks like I'm going to start hating on mono.